# Crystal reports out of range value vendor error 242

Tags: crystal-reports

I am writing a report in Crystal 2020 that has previously worked in Crystal 2008 based on data pulled from an SQL view which shows the sum of qty based on a date range between today and 5 days ago. The report populates fine until I put the where clause in the SQL view.
The SQL is

```
SELECT Company, SourceWarehouse, TargetWarehouse, StockCode, SUM(GtrQuantity) AS TrfQty, CONVERT(varchar, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME), 23) AS LookOutDate
FROM     dbo.vwGtrSuggestionsQtyByDate
WHERE  (TransactionDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, - 5, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
GROUP BY Company, SourceWarehouse, TargetWarehouse, StockCode
```

The SQL view runs without any problem so I am stuck as to how I can get the results into my report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your ***TransactionDate*** is a **DateTime** rather than **Date**.
So you need the rest of the WHERE clause to use DateTime rather than Date expressions.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. The TransactionDate field was varchar so converted to date and everything work fine now.